# How re-order activities in android?

Tags: android, authentication, android-activity, homescreen

I have a simple problem. In my app I have 3 activities A,B,C. Activity A is the main activity.On some action on activity A it takes to activity B and then after some action it goes to activity C. When I am at activity C, I pressed home button and the home screen came. Now when I click on the app icon again it starts activity C again. But I want the activity A should be coming as I have to ask the password. I want all the activities should be finished when I press home button and when I click app icon again the login activity i.e activity A should be coming. Can anybody give me some solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your firing intent to go from one activity to another like this ----->

Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);

then add this thing to your code then all thing will get fine ---->

addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) like this ----->

Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivty(intent);

NOTE---> here (this) means your A activity.

Answer (score 0):

Activity Lifecycle:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Use these callback functions to recognize what happens to your activity. When the user hits the homebutton, call finish() in your activity C. Activity B will regonize that C was finished and will finish() too. Than you are back at Activity A.

Answer (score 0):

You can control your app while is onPause status (when the user press home).

```
 protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

}
```

Here you can do all the stuff you want.

Another way is to intercept "Home" button, and before the app goes in background it quickly come back to activity A.

Answer (score 0):

Much of this answer is based off of the [lifecycle of an activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

When a user hits the home button, at the very least, an activity will be paused. Use the onPause() function to detect this. There are a couple of things which you could do from this point, the most basic would be to just end your activity C. Calling the finish() will kill the activity. This will allow you to navigate through the activity as normal, but will kill it if you quit it.

If the activity gets more complex, the onPause() might be called for other reasons, like memory is needed. It might be worth adding a bit of extra logic to detect if the person is in a sub function or not.

An alternative is to use the function onRestart(), and simply finish the activity. This might spare some of the oddness.

Answer (score 0):

I changed in Manifest file and I removed the intent filters from my activity B and C as launcher. Now whenever I press the app icon i reach to login activity.